# How to use dig to send DNS queries to servers of interest directly? (not through my local DNS resolver)

Tags: domain-name-system, dig

How can I use dig to send a dns query to servers directly? (not through local DNS resolver).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because Serverfault should not be expected to be reading manuals as a service.

Answer (score 1):

If you type your question into Google the [first result](http://droptips.com/using-dig-to-query-a-specific-dns-server-name-server-directly-linux-bsd-osx) gives you your answer.

```
dig droptips.com @ns.123-reg.co.uk
```

What is it with SO today? People have forgotten how to use Google?

Comment: Don't indulge lazy question askers with an answer, just ignore it and move on. Downvote if you feel it deserves it.